# Debug freezing safari on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, safari

**Problem:** So I have that website which is developed with Google Web Toolkit (gwt). However, since the recent patch, the application freezes at a certain point for iPhone5 users with Safari. Other iOS-Devices like iPad seem to work fine so far.

**My approach:**
However, since I do not have an iPhone, I tried various online tools simulating websites on the iPhone but neither of them is having any trouble. Then I tried the Chrome's built-in device emulator which did not cause any trouble, as well.

**Question:** Is there any way, I can debug this case or at least reproduce it given the fact that I do not have access to an iPhone?
In case the answer is 'no': how can I debug a freezing Safari given the fact that I get access to an iPhone?

**Bonus question:** Why do the iPhone emulators not freeze? At least I would expect them to behave in a strange way or give me some message, that something might be wrong.

Comment: If you have a Mac you could try the iOS simulator in Xcode. You can open it from the menu bar under Xcode -> Open developer tool -> iOS simulator. It should behave fairly similarly.

Comment: That's the point: I do not have a Mac. Is it possible to launch it in a VM or do I have to buy an iOS licence therefore?

Comment: Theoritically it is possible to launch it in a VM, it's just an OS like others, you can find several resources via Google on how to do so. You don't have to buy an iOS license for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by using browserstack.com, which emulates an OS environment in-browser, where I could use the iPhone-Dev-Tools. Other browser-based emulators did not work as they did not emulate the OS and thus did not recreate the errors described.